# How to prevent debuild from performing a clean?

Tags: packaging, deb

I am trying to edit an Apache module on Debian (strictly, I'm doing this on Raspbian Jessie-Lite), and am broadly following the [Debian build instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/src/debian; cd ~/src/debian
$ apt-get source apache2-bin
$ cd apache2-2.4.10
$ debuild -b -uc -us
```

And the build process takes roughly one and a half hours on an olde original Pi. Which is fine. Once!
But I believe the build process is performing a `make clean` and so after a minor edit of a single mod_*.c file, it wants to rebuild the entire thing, which is kind of slowing down my development!

I have tried adding `-dc` to the `debuild` command, but then it didn't build anything. I even tried deleting the target mod_*.so file to "encourage" it into rebuilding it, but still no!

UPDATE 2016-08-21: Adding -nc to the debuild command does not cause modules to be recompiled. Here's the output from that command:

```
$ debuild -b -uc -us -nc
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b -nc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package apache2
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.4.10-10+deb8u5
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution jessie-security
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Salvatore Bonaccorso <carnil@debian.org>
 dpkg-source --before-build apache2-2.4.10
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture armhf
 debian/rules build
dh build --parallel --with autotools_dev
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --parallel --with autotools_dev
 dpkg-genchanges -b >../apache2_2.4.10-10+deb8u5_armhf.changes
dpkg-genchanges: binary-only upload (no source code included)
 dpkg-source --after-build apache2-2.4.10
dpkg-buildpackage: binary-only upload (no source included)
Now running lintian...
N: 16 tags overridden (1 error, 4 warnings, 11 info)
Finished running lintian.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `-nc` option to your `debuild` command line. This may expose problems in the build system or the packaging though, so be prepared. But for small fixes it usually works fine.

However, as the `apache2` source package uses debhelper (like many other packages), this alone is not enough, because debhelper also keeps its own journal of completed steps in separate log files for each binary package. These can be removed entirely by `dh_clean`. But to get debhelper redo no more than the necessary work, truncate only the relevant one by

```
sed -i '/^dh_auto_build$/Q' debian/apache2-bin.debhelper.log
```

before running `debuild -nc`.

Comment: Thank you too for your reply! It didn't work though! :D In fact, the output, and the duration taken were identical to removing the clean bits from debian/rules. I've updated the question with the output from debuild with -nc in case it helps.

Comment: What happens if you invoke plain `make` in the top level source directory after making your code changes? If that rebuilds what you need, try `debuild -nc` after that.

Comment: `make` does do something; it compiles bits in `[top-level-source]/modules/mappers/.libs/` but the .so file in there is larger than the .so file that is installed (9.4K vs 35K). However, the file that a full `debuild` builds ends up in `[top-level-source]/debian/apache2-bin/usr/lib/apache2/modules/`. So my doing a `make` followed by `debuild -nc` didn't result in a file I could install.

Comment: I'm might be saying what you already know, but it seems to me that there's the Apache distribution, along with all it's make files, and then there's the Debian patches and **its** makes files... and the two are separate? And I'm also wondering if the Debian stuff doesn't just recompile everything because easier/safer to do so! Maybe?!

Comment: The size difference is probably the result of stripping. Anyway, this in encouraging. Now, run `sed -i '/^dh_auto_build$/Q' debian/apache2-bin.debhelper.log` (supposing your changes concern the `apache2-bin` binary package). Then run `debuild -nc`.

Comment: That works - cheers!!! :D

Answer (score 5):

Inside the debian directory there's a rules file. It's a essentially a make file.  If you remove all the directives about cleaning and then add

```
override_dh_clean:
```

And put nothing in it no cleaning will happen (at all).  Be careful though this might cause build problems, not likely but might.  Another alternative is to not change anything and use the -j option to do a parallel build.  Not sure the advantage that'd give on a raspberry pi.

Rules file should look like [this](https://salsa.debian.org/apache-team/apache2/blob/master/debian/rules).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried editing debian/rules, but whilst it is much quicker (less than 7 minutes), it doesn't re-compile the module I've edited.

Comment: Having had a look around, there's a lot of .mk files in there too, but I'm utterly lost as to what calls what and when!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; Scite debian package has in `debian/rules`:

```
...
BUILD_DATE="$(date --utc --date="@${SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH:-$(date +%s)}" "+%b %d %Y %T")"
override CPPFLAGS += -DBUILD_DATE="\"$(BUILD_DATE)\""

%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_build:
        dh_auto_build --sourcedirectory=scintilla/gtk -- GTK3=1 $(BUILD_LUA)
        dh_auto_build --sourcedirectory=scite/gtk -- gnomeprefix=/usr GTK3=1 $(BUILD_LUA)
....
```

Essentially, `override_dh_auto_build` calls the make, which detects changed source files and rebuilds only changed ones. However, even if `debian/rules` sets `BUILD_DATE`, running:

```
fakeroot debian/rules -j$(nproc) override_dh_auto_build
```

... will fail at some cpp source files that use BUILD_DATE as a define. The solution is to explicitly specify this variable on the command line call:

```
fakeroot debian/rules -j$(nproc) CPPFLAGS+=-DBUILD_DATE="" override_dh_auto_build
```

... and then compilation passes (additional bonus is that a new .deb is not created, so you don't have to wait for that). Essentially, this helps to rerun just the rebuild process for changed files that gives you the .so/.exe, without packaging a .deb.